# onitemlongclick get id from sqlite then delete

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having a hard time with my delete via onitemlongclick, I am new to android so please spare me.

here is my processes

1. enlist my data from sqlite>                                  ***done**
2. set onitemlongclick listener then pop up dialog for delete   ***done**
3. get the row 'id' and delete it from sqlite.                  ***not done**

assuming i got this table

```
 tableuser


 uniqid  | name | username
     2d1 | e    | e1
     cc2 | d    | d1
     2cd | c    | c1
```

so far I got is

```
public void list() {
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.newrecord_item,
                accompList);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    } 

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewRecords.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Record");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Delete Employee Record?");
                alertDialog.setButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dataAdapter.getItem(arg2);


                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton2("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
                return false;
            }
```

I need to know how to perform delete on android

Comment: do you have a custom adapter? to you have a list with the items that you use to populate the list? You have to provide more code and have a more explicit question.

Comment: what is your question exactly ?

Comment: @Dyna yes, I already have my list. I need to know how to perform delete

Comment: more code please @kodewrecker.

Comment: aeg3 is your id, just delete data based on this id

Comment: @pskink ow sorry I forgot to tell the id is not visible in user's end. that's one of my problem, how to get id by just longclicking on row.

Comment: do you have an object with the values uniqid, name and username? do you have a list with this objects?

Comment: what you see when Log.d(arg3)

Comment: @pskink just number 1  or 2 or 3

Comment: that is the id inside the listview, not the userid!

Comment: @dyna yeah, I think so.
post is updated included the custom adapter

Comment: this is not complete! what is the list: `accompList` ? Where is the code for your `MyCustomAdapter` ?

Comment: @Dyna just a bunch of setters and getters

Comment: I don't know if you don't understand my questions or don't want to. anyway I give up on helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in getView():

For every view you return, set tag for view. Tag should be the unique id as you have told in above table.

```
view.setTag(uniqueId[position]);

return view;
```

position is integer value received in getView().

And when user taps on list item, you can get the tapped view. Get the tag from the view.

```
Integer uniqueId = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
```

Then, use this uniqueId integer value, write delete sql query and pass this unique Id, such that row with this uniqueId should be deleted.

And commit database changes.